# webrequest object to csv in tornado

Tags: python, csv, tornado

I have the following webrequest object body generated by uploading the csv:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZfGb9EY1D9p7BTV9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="vb_bpm.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

10/05/2015,00:08:17,8,3960,2,52503,19824
10/05/2015,00:19:35,8,3960,2,52542,19824
10/05/2015,02:21:21,8,3960,2,55366,19824
10/05/2015,02:32:11,8,3960,2,55942,19824
10/05/2015,02:43:13,8,3960,2,56139,19824
10/05/2015,02:54:09,8,3960,2,56750,19824
10/05/2015,03:05:08,8,3960,2,57007,19824
10/05/2015,03:16:10,8,3960,2,57040,19824
10/05/2015,03:27:00,8,3960,2,57633,19824
10/05/2015,03:37:54,8,3960,2,58306,19824
10/05/2015,03:48:47,8,3960,2,58984,19824

------WebKitFormBoundaryZfGb9EY1D9p7BTV9--
```

I would like to save this into a new csv file.
Following gives the above output:

```
def csv_handle(self, request, response) :
        print request.body()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a "webrequest object"? Tornado's request objects have a body attribute, but no body method. Assuming you mean a Tornado request and the use of parens on `request.body` was a typo, you can use the `files` attribute of the request. `body` is always the raw request body, which in this case includes a `multipart/form-data` wrapper. Tornado recognizes the `multipart/form-data` content type (for non-streaming requests) and parses it into the `files` object. In this case you can find your csv file under `request.files["file"][0].body`.

Comment: The `request.files` attribute gives easy access to the uploaded file, but it still needs validation. Hence I would propose running any uploaded file through a validator such as the regexp in my answer.

Comment: when i am using request.files["file"][0].body,it gives me a TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' @ben-darnell

Comment: What exactly is your request object? It doesn't sound like tornado's HTTPRequest since it has instance methods where tornado has attributes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest strict validation of all uploaded data to prevent code injection and data quality degradation.

My solution would be to run the uploaded lines through a regexp:

```
import re

lines = str(request.body).split()
p = "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4},\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2},\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+"
filtered_body = "\n".join(filter(lambda l: re.match(p, l), lines))

print "Original:\n%s\n" % request.body
print "Filtered:\n%s\n" % filtered_body
```

Resulting output on your data:

```
Original:
------WebKitFormBoundaryZfGb9EY1D9p7BTV9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="vb_bpm.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

10/05/2015,00:08:17,8,3960,2,52503,19824
10/05/2015,00:19:35,8,3960,2,52542,19824
10/05/2015,02:21:21,8,3960,2,55366,19824
10/05/2015,02:32:11,8,3960,2,55942,19824
10/05/2015,02:43:13,8,3960,2,56139,19824
10/05/2015,02:54:09,8,3960,2,56750,19824
10/05/2015,03:05:08,8,3960,2,57007,19824
10/05/2015,03:16:10,8,3960,2,57040,19824
10/05/2015,03:27:00,8,3960,2,57633,19824
10/05/2015,03:37:54,8,3960,2,58306,19824
10/05/2015,03:48:47,8,3960,2,58984,19824

------WebKitFormBoundaryZfGb9EY1D9p7BTV9--

Filtered:
10/05/2015,00:08:17,8,3960,2,52503,19824
10/05/2015,00:19:35,8,3960,2,52542,19824
10/05/2015,02:21:21,8,3960,2,55366,19824
10/05/2015,02:32:11,8,3960,2,55942,19824
10/05/2015,02:43:13,8,3960,2,56139,19824
10/05/2015,02:54:09,8,3960,2,56750,19824
10/05/2015,03:05:08,8,3960,2,57007,19824
10/05/2015,03:16:10,8,3960,2,57040,19824
10/05/2015,03:27:00,8,3960,2,57633,19824
10/05/2015,03:37:54,8,3960,2,58306,19824
10/05/2015,03:48:47,8,3960,2,58984,19824
```

Saving the lines to file is straightforward.